# Display data based on a date period which covers more than a 24 hour period based on Start time on one day and a finish time on another day

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project that displays data on given days between given times. Example: display data every Monday starting at 18:00 through to Tuesday 03:00.
Currently to make this work I have to create two records, one from Monday 18:00 until 23:59 and a second record from Tuesday 00:00 until 03:00.

Is there a way in which I would only require one record to cover the example of the Monday/Tuesday issue.

The SQL Query that returns the data looks like:

```
PHP Variables
$DayOfWeek = date('N');
$NowTime = date('H:i:s');
$NowDate = date('Y-m-d');

MySQL Query
SELECT RecordID, ClientImageName,FromDateTime,ToDateTime, Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,Day6,Day7 
FROM Promotions2017 WHERE ClientID = '".$ClientID."' AND DisplayID = '". $DisplayID."'
AND '".$NowTime."' BETWEEN FromTime AND ToTime 
AND '".$NowDate."' >= FromDate AND '".$NowDate."' <= ToDate
AND  '".$DayOfWeek."' IN(Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,Day6,Day7)
```

Comment: Why is date and time separate fields in your table?

Comment: @Phaelaxz Hi, the date and time can be and should be one field, I take that onboard.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and some sample data. The `Day1` to `Day7` columns definitely have a bit of a smell about them.